# Android Studio(Imagery Material Design)

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I've been struggling on finding this type of design on google but no luck.
I looked here [Google Material Design(Imagery)](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#) but I can't find a tutorial for it.
I want my app to looked like this.

[image: I want it to be Like this]

And when i scrolled it down it would be like this..
(Photos not mine)
[image]

Tutorial link will do. I'm not asking for code. It's best if I'll learn by the help of tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: will this work on pre-lollipop devices?

Pre-requisites
Android SDK v22
Android Build Tools v22.0.1
Android Support Repository r16 (for v22.2.1)